# Javascript, change css background image when colour changes

Tags: javascript, css

i made this script for my forum and i was wondering if someone could help me out, when the color changes to red, i want the background image to be:

`/images/redshield.png`

and on green

`/images/greenshield.png`

here is the script

```
function flashy(index) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        if (index > 1) {
            index = 0;
            for (x = 0; x < document.getElementsByClassName('style113').length; x++) {
                document.getElementsByClassName('style113')[x].style.color = 'Lime';
            }
        } else {
            for (x = 0; x < document.getElementsByClassName('style113').length; x++) {
                document.getElementsByClassName('style113')[x].style.color = 'Red';
            }
        }
        index++;
        flashy(index);
    }, 100);
}
```

Comment: You can set `backgroundImage` using value`url(/path/to/image/)` in same manner which you set `color` property

Comment: Why not create 2 separate classes (one with lime background and greenshield.png, and another with red background and redshield.png), and swap the classes, instead of working with the style attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on what is the element you want to change the background image for, but guessing it is the same elements that get the color attribute, then:

```
function flashy(index){
 setTimeout(function(){
  if(index > 1){
   index = 0;for(x = 0; x <            document.getElementsByClassName('style113').length; x++){
    document.getElementsByClassName('style113')[x].style.color = 'Lime';
    document.getElementsByClassName('style113')[x].style.backgroundImage = "url('/images/greenshield.png')";
   }
  }else{
   for(x = 0; x < document.getElementsByClassName('style113').length; x++){
    document.getElementsByClassName('style113')[x].style.color = 'Red';
    document.getElementsByClassName('style113')[x].style.backgroundImage = "url('/images/redshield.png')";
    }
  }index++;flashy(index);
 }, 100);
}
```

Comment: how do i get it to play audio if the user hovers over the element?